# paypal ipn wrong encoding issue

Tags: encoding, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have problem with ipn from paypal. I'm sending them data utf-8 encoded(e.g. "Naročilo št" as item name) and when somebody pays they send me response which is malformed: "Naro�~D�~Milo �~E¡t."(response claims that is UTF-8 encoded) and then when I try to validate that payment I get that it's invalid.

I've tried to change the "buy button" encoding on my paypal profile  but it's not working(I still get response with wrongly encoded characters). Anybody have an idea how to fix that issue? And I would rather avoid transforming item names to plain ascii or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

According to [this](https://community.jboss.org/thread/38625)

> When the Servlet container receives the request, it always pass the request parameters to your program decoded in ISO-8859-1 encoding. (e.g. Browser encoded in UTF-8 but container decoded in ISO-8859-1.) Thus your servlet or JSP will always receive garbage for characters other than ISO-8859-1 encoding.

so the solution to my problem was acquiring request parameters that way:

```
String value = request.getParameter("mytext");  
try{  
   value = new String(value.getBytes("8859_1"), "UTF-8");  
}catch(java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e){  
   System.err.println(e);  
}
```